# Installing pyQT on OSX for python 3.2

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, osx-mountain-lion

NOTE: I'm using python 3

I've been trying to install pyQT on Mac OsX Mountain Lion and I have not had much success so far. I'm fairly new to this so I don't even want to think about setting everything up manually.

Heres the error Im getting which I believe means that there is no easy_install script for installing pyQT. Ive also tried macports however pyQT is not supported for python3 yet on that. Does anyone have any simple solution to getting pyQT installed on osX?

Downloading http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.9.5/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.9.5.tar.gz
Processing PyQt-x11-gpl-4.9.5.tar.gz
error: Couldn't find a setup script in /tmp/easy_install-ZiD0mx/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.9.5.tar.gz
new-host-6:~ Eric$

macports just gives the error "port install not found"

Answer (score 6):

I don't have specific instructions, but here is an overview of what you need

**Install Qt:** Either via macports, homebrew, source, or a [binary build](http://releases.qt-project.org/qt4/source/qt-mac-opensource-4.8.3.dmg).

**Install sip** from [source](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download)

```
python configure.py --arch=x86_64
make && make install
```

**Install PyQt4** from [source](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download). You want the mac source. Not X11 (linux)

```
python configure.py
make && make install
```

PyQt4 should locate sip and your Qt install.

You cannot simply install it from easy_install because it is a bit more involved. PyQt depends on SIP and a Qt installation for linking. I recommend homebrew over macports for package installing. You can use it to get Qt: `brew install qt`